# Binding unique URLs to XML site map ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, data-binding

So, I'm new to ASP.NET and website development in general. I've run into a problem  using data binding to an XML file to build a site map for an ASP.NET application. Here's the first portion of the sitemap:

```
<Privo>
  <child display="Current Projects">
    <child display="Amifostin">
      <child display="Experiments">
        <leaf>HTT</leaf>
        <leaf>MTT</leaf>
        <leaf>HPLC</leaf>
        <leaf>UV-Spec</leaf>
      </child>
```

And the data binding from the site.master file:

```
<DataBindings>                                                        
   <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="child" TextField="display" />
   <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="leaf" TextField="#InnerText" />
</DataBindings>
```

What'd I'd like to do it something like this:

```
 <leaf url="ExperimentsView.aspx/HTT">HTT<leaf>
```

and

```
  <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="leaf" TextField="#InnnerText" NavigateUrl="url"/>
```

BUT, here's the problem: when I try to bind the NavigateUrl, the only thing I can do is bind a *type* of node to a url - meaning, every leaf will link the the same url. Is there a way to bind a field of the leaf nodes to a (unique) url, or will I have to make different DataMembers for each unique url?

Note: yes, I know about Web.sitemap. That's what I was using when the project lead told me that he wants to use XML data binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the NavigateUrlField property to do this (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenodebinding.navigateurlfield.aspx)